# Parsing time to Datetime with Timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have a time like this:

```
Fri Dec 04 14:51:22 CST 2020
```

I want to parse it as Timestamp with Timezone in Python, I am not able to achieve this with regular methods.
Could someone please help me in doing this efficiently.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `parse` function from the [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package.

```
from dateparser import parse
dt = parse("Fri Dec 04 14:51:22 CST 2020")
```

Comment: here the CST represent china standard time, but parse is detecting it as "China Standard time". Could you please tell me the clean work around for this? Thanks.